# How to recursively synchronize file timestamps across servers?

Tags: backup, rsync, timestamps

Suppose I run an rsync command to mirror a server, but forget to supply the -t option. The mirror will now have different timestamps to the original. What is the easiest way to fix this, without transferring all the files all over again?

Comment: Rsync should be intelligent enough to only update the timestamps instead of sending the whole files, AFAIK. Is this not your experience? Try using `rsync --itemize-changes` to see what it is doing exactly. For an explanatian, see the man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the same command again, but include the `-c` option. This tells rsync to run an efficient checksum on the file and make the decision to transfer/not-transfer based on the checksum.