# How do I alter datestamps of files recursively but only if the existing file doesn't match a particular date?

Tags: bash, rsync, timestamps

I have a folder (many files and subfolders, a few hundred gigabytes). I duplicated the folder with rsync, but forgot to preserve the timestamps.

The new folder has now had many new files added to it and existing files modified.

I need to copy across the timestamps of the old folder to the new folder, but only if the files haven't been modified after Jul 9 2021.

I don't think rsync will do it.
I think I'll have to use `touch -t`, but need an efficient way to process all the files.
Is there a better way? Or, how can I process all the files and update the timestamps if the files haven't been modified since Jul 9.

Thanks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200408/can-rsync-fix-time-stamps-without-redownloading, https://serverfault.com/questions/344731/rsync-copying-over-timestamps-only

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't what I'm looking for. The answer in that post would update ALL the timestamps from the source to the destination. I only want to apply the changes to files that have not been changed since. The scenario given there is a mirror. Mine is two copies, one with newer changes, one with the correct timestamps.

Comment: Possible solution: recopy original to a new folder, maintaining timestamp, then copy the other folder on top using either check size or checksum to only overwrite files that have changed. Will write this as a solution if it works.

Comment: You can use find to limit the ones being used to the "suspect" timestamp.  Then you can either feed that file list to `rsync` or use some of the other techniques to update the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that should work:

```bsh
find /path/to/newdir -type f -not -newermt 09jul2021 -printf './%P\000' | rsync -r --files-from=- -0 --size-only --times /path/to/olddir/ /path/to/newdir/
```

The first half of the command generates a null-separated list of files in `"newdir"` that haven't been modified since July 9, 2021 formatted with paths relative to the synced directory.

The second half of the command runs `rsync` on that list of files and changes their modification timestamps in `"newdir"` to match the ones in `"olddir"`

Comment: It should be noted that it would still retransfer the files that have different size or type between the two directories. You probably don't want the `-r` which would cause whole directory trees to be transferred if a regular file in newdir happens to be a dir in oldir.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way wound up being to use rsync itself.

By copying back onto the old folder with the --size-only flag, only files that were newer than the old folder were copied, thus it didn't affect the timestamps of existing files.

This isn't going to be a perfect answer for everyone, but the risk here of small changs being lost with the --size-only flag are not going to be a problem for me.

I ran it with --dry-run first, then checked the results with diff to make sure things were working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `find`/`touch`.

```
cd newdir && find . -depth ! -newermt 2021-07-10 -exec \
  touch -hr '../olddir/{}' '{}' \;
```

(note that 2021-07-10 here means 2021-07-10 at 00:00:00 in the morning, change  to `! -newertmt 2021-07-10T23:59:59.99999999` if you want to exclude files last modified at the very nanosecond at midnight).

Note that it runs one `touch` per file, so won't be efficient.

If you have a `busybox` configured so that the `sh` applet can invoke other applets without fork+exec, it can be sped up with:

```
cd newdir && find . -depth ! -newermt 2021-07-10 -exec \
  busybox sh -c '
    for file do
      touch -hr "../olddir/$file" "$file"
    done' sh {} +
```

Though beware you need busybox 1.34.0 or newer for its `touch` applet to also copy the nanosecond part of the timestamps.